# How to understand "stood framed in the doorway"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> For a split second, Uncle Vernon stood framed in the doorway; ...

The phrase sounds, to me, a vivid account. I could imagine that Uncle Vernon standing there in the doorway be just like a big picture with a frame around it. But I'm not sure if it's the correct way to understand it. What are the native speakers' take for this sentence?

Comment: "the correct way to make of it" is not idiomatic. You're not sure **what to make of it** or you're not sure **if this is the correct way to understand it**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO, it's an amazing way to tell that the person was *frozen* for a moment. Well, since the *place* he got froze was the doorway, it might appear that he's stationary and the whole picture looked like a frame.

It's *worth noting* that in *photography,* you *frame against something* to make the photo stand out!

[See the example:](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/frame)

> *She stood there, **framed against** the doorway.*